# Sitecore Content Search (Lucene) - Between<T>() not work

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, lucene.net

I am using Sitecore 8.1 update 1 with ContentSearch feature. I configure my index as below:

(I want to search Broker/Client office by Latitude and Longitude)

1) in index.config

```
      <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">

          <field fieldName="latitude"         storageType="NO" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Decimal" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          </field>
          <field fieldName="longitude"         storageType="NO" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Decimal" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          </field>
```

2) Ok now use Luke.net tool to check its value

[image in Luke.net tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAyLO.png)

3) my SearchResultItem class:

```
    [IndexField("latitude")]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

    [IndexField("longitude")]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
```

4) at my service class, I would like to try Between method to search Latitude/Longitude in range but it does not work. I try equal (==) method and it works. I think my index is ok but maybe there is something wrong in my search syntax. Could you please help?

```
    //TODO: Testing -----------------
    var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<BrokerSearchIndexItem>();

    // IF i use this line (BETWEEN) --> NOT work ??
    query = query.Where(item => (item.Latitude.Between(-34, -33, Inclusion.Both)
                                    && item.Longitude.Between(149, 151, Inclusion.Both)));

    // If I use this line (EQUAL) --> work !
    //query = query.Where(item => item.Latitude == -33.737643m && item.Longitude == 150.856664m);

    var searchResult = query.GetResults();
```

5) I already read this tutorial [(link)](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/linq_to_sitecore) and my search log as well, it seems Between method give me right log but not sure why I get nothing

```
    9636 21:10:03 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (steadfast_broker_location): +latitude:[-34 TO -33] +longitude:[149 TO 151] - Filter : 
    9636 21:10:03 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (steadfast_broker_location): +latitude:[-34 TO -33] +longitude:[149 TO 151] - Filter : 
    9636 21:10:03 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (steadfast_broker_location): +latitude:[-34 TO -33] +longitude:[149 TO 151] - Filter :
```

Comment: Not sure but try '-34.000000m' instead of just '-34'.
Or as workaround this should help:
query = query.Where(item => (item.Latitude > -34.000000m && item.Latitude < -33.000000m) && (item.Longitude > 149.000000m && item.Longitude < 151.000000m))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Lucene Spatial Search Support module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Lucene_Spatial_Search_Support.aspx)

It will provide:

- New Sitecore field "Google Map" that will store the lat/long and provide a map interface in the Content Editor.
- Index schema updates to store the lat and long values.
- Updates to Sitecore ContentSearch to provide methods for geospatial searches.

There's also a [module for Solr](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Solr_Spatial_Search_Support.aspx).

Comment: Thank Nathan Hase,
But I also use  Between to search other Decimal field in range, so I still would like to fix this bug for other case :)

Comment: OK, try taking a look at the spatial source code to see what they are doing with the predicate. I also notice that your Between example is using integers while your Equals example uses decimals.

Comment: Thank you again, 
I will try to read that module source code.  About my sample code, I did try with decimal in Between statement but it does not work.  In my solution, I pass decimal variable, not hardcode constant value

Comment: Right on, just things to check :) You can also take a look at the Lucene query that is being run and test that with Luke for more perspective. Queries get logged at /data/logs/search.log